# VBA Code to filter between a range of dates

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm looking to filter my table on dates based off a user friendly drop down box.

As it stands, the dropdown box is populated by just month names.
There is then a hidden formula that transfers these names into 2 dates in cells U4 and U5.
The dates are the first day of the month and last day of month.

I want to be able to select the month and then click a button to filter a list object table below on the dates.

here is my current code:

```
Sub Filters()

    Range("U4", "U5").Copy
    Range("V4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False`

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("V4").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("V5").Value, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

But the filter does not "execute"
I've copied the cells to V4 and V5 to see if the formulas were anything to do with it, but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking dates from formulas, take the raw underlying values and transfer them directly.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("V4:V5") = .Range("U4:U5").Value2

    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter  '<~~turn off any previous filtering operation
    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & Application.Min(.Range("V4").Value2, .Range("V5").Value), _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<=" & Application.Max(.Range("V4").Value2, .Range("V5").Value)
End With
```

I'm not sure if there might have been some confusion as to the beginning and end of the period to filter but I added some worksheet functions so that they were ordered correctly.